# Drawing special border in ios

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to know how to draw special border in ios, like the twitter app in iphone.[image: see the arrow-shaped sign]
The border has a special allow mark which point to the actived camera icon. how?

Thanks!

Comment: That's a custom bar with a static border and an animated arrow. Look here for the arrow code: http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/17/twitter-app-tab-bar-animation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create this using a png-image (UIImageView) which is positioned accordingly to the selected item.